# Google Foobar Challenge: Peculiar Balance

Tags: algorithm, math, ternary, ternary-representation

I'm solving a problem where you convert a base-10 positive integer between `0` and `1000000000` to a balanced ternary form as part of Google's code challenge. It seems to work for various cases I've tested under the constraint, but it fails tests 4 and 5 for some reason. Can you spot what's wrong with this?

```
def answer(binary):

    # Convert to ternary
    ternary = convertToTernary(binary)

    # Conver to balanced ternary
    balancedTernary = balance(ternary)

    return balancedTernary

def balance(tForm):
    tForm.append(0)
    bTernary = tForm

    i = 0;
    N = len(tForm)
    for i in range(N - 1):
        if tForm[i] == 2:
            tForm[i] = 'L'  # Convert to custom convention now
            tForm[i+1] += 1
        elif tForm[i] > 2:
            tForm[i] = 0
            tForm[i+1] += 1

    # Apply custom convention to the rest of the coefficients
    for i in range(len(tForm)):
        if tForm[i] == 0:
            tForm[i] = '-'
        elif tForm[i] == 1:
            tForm[i] = 'R'
        else:
            tForm[i] = 'L'

    return bTernary

def convertToTernary(binary):
    tForm = []

    while binary > 0:
        tForm.append(binary % 3)
        binary /= 3

    return tForm
```

Comment: Tell us when this challenge is over, so that we don't spoil it.

Comment: Please include the failing test cases you mention, or at the very least link to them!

Comment: There's no indication of exactly what failed but only that it failed tests 4 and 5 out of 5 total.

Comment: You should include the problem details in your post, especially when (as here) the site is not publicly accessible

Comment: I've tested it against my 10 liner and it gives the same answers. Maybe the problem lies in the output format? It seems that you precede the meaningful answer with 0's or -'s.

Comment: for the record, it not a base-10 int... it's "just" an integer but you sniffed right it's about converting to balanced ternary

Comment: Point us to where we can challenge the challenge